# Prefill textarea with string '</textarea>'

Tags: html, mustache

This is my textarea for editing a blog comment, the textare content is filled using mustache.js:

```
<textarea name="content">{{content}}</textarea>
```

Now if the user typed a html tag into his comment - for example he commented `</textarea> my text here` - the edit textarea content will show `&lt;/textarea&gt; my text here`

But if I change `{{content}}` to `{{{content}}}`, the resulting html of the comment content will be something like this:

```
    <textarea name="content"></textarea> my text here</textarea>
```

Which obviously doesn't work either.

How do I solve this problem? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was my mistake.
I escaped the string once from server side, and then escaped it again using mustache.
The actual content filled was `&amp;lt;`, not `&lt;` thus resulting in a textarea displaying `&lt;`

Comment: When I try to accept my own answer it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". I don't really understand what it mean, maybe I will have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer. Sorry for the inconvenient :(

Comment: Ah ! , nothing to be sorry infact I forgot that you can't accept your answer within 2 days, so yes you will have to come 2 days later to accept your answer. :)